# (Objective-C) Reading multiple words from a txt file from resources

Tags: ios, objective-c, text, nsstring

I'm new to objective-c, I have decent experience with C, C++ . How would I read a text file with 4 lines of words. I would have to read each line separately and store each of them in their respective NSStrings. i.e, 4 strings with the 4 lines of text in the file. I'm still new to the methods in Obj-C, so a little help would be much appreciated !

PS: I've started reading on CoreData, but I doubt if that is related to this.

Comment: Do you have the file string loaded and you need to parse / split it? What is the scope of the problem?

Comment: Also, if the file is a resource, can you change the format to make life easier for you?

Comment: Yes, I can change the format ! I plan to have multiple levels (in a game) and each levels would have relevant words in their respective text files. I would have to read the 4 words for each level using just 1 file/ level !

Comment: And these 4 words would be saved in separate NSStrings and their Labels in the UI would be updated for the user

Comment: While the answer from @Tark will work then, take a look at storing the strings in an array, saved as a plist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First get the path of the file in the app bundle:

```
NSString *filename = @"textfile.txt";
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[filename stringByDeletingPathExtension] ofType:[filename pathExtension]];
```

Next load the files contents into a string and split them into an array of strings:

```
NSString *text = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:path encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:NULL];
NSArray *lines = [text componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet newlineCharacterSet]];
```

Hey presto.

Comment: Thanks You ! :) ,And I would take the array through a 'for' loop to create 4 strings right ?

Comment: Never mind, I saved them in NSStrings using [arrayName objectAtIndex:]; Thanks